# Mistake in importing the class

Tags: python, import, importerror

I was working with importing classes (please see my code below) and I ran into the following mistake:

Below is the code of the file `admin_instance.py` and I see the squiggly line under admin in `admin_instance.py`

```
import admin

my_admin = admin.Admin('john', 'doe', 30, 'USA')
my_admin.describe_user()
my_admin.admin_privileges.show_privileges()
```

and this one is the code of `admin.py`

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, location):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.location = location

    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"The full name of the user is {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}." 
              f" He is {self.age} years old and he is from {self.location}.")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello, {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}!")

class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges = ['can add post', 'can delete post', 'can ban user']):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("Administrator's set of privileges are: ", sep = "", end = " ")
        for x in self.privileges:
            print(x, end = " ")

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, location):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, location)
        self.admin_privileges = Privileges()
```

The code is running in VS Code, but it says that `Import 'admin' could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports) [Ln 1, Col 8]`.

Both of my files are in the same directory, so I'm not sure what the mistake is here. Please help me fix that issue! Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project folder you have opened is not the parent folder of "admin.py" and "admin_instance.py" (or the path of "admin.py" would be relative instead of "c: > ..."). So those files are being treated as isolated Python code files.

Select VScode menu "File" -> "Open Folder" and open "C:...\Python work\importing", and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! May I ask how you figured out that the project folder is not the parent folder of "admin.py" and "admin_instance.py"? It's not clear to me at all.

Comment: See the bar over your code. It shows the path of the file being edited. In your screenshot, it says "C: > Users > ..." which is an absolute path instead of a relative path. So, the file you are editing must have been opened from outside of the project folder.

Comment: I think I kinda understand what you said, but to clarify, let me explain it in my own words. So, in the bar above the code, I see `C:>Users>firar>...>importing>admin_instance.py`, which is an absolute path to my Python file. Since my file imports `admin`, it means it uses some file from the folder with the name `importing`. That's why the last step in the directory should be `importing`, right?

Comment: I think you've got it.